# Is there a way to group this and compare?

Tags: python, pandas

Quick question about pandas.

How am I able to find the amount of times this list shows up in this DataFrame?

['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']

| Line | Generation | SNP_1 | SNP_2 | SNP_3 | SNP_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2021 | A | A | A | A |
| A | 2022 | A | C | C | G |
| A | 2022 | A | C | T | C |
| A | 2022 | A | C | C | G |

The idea is: for each row, from column at position [2:] and onwards, does the list match the row, in that same order.

While grouping would be nice it's not neccessary, i.e. groupby(['Line', 'Generation']) and count how many times the list occurs yielding results: "1" for group: Line B/Generation 2021, "0" for Line A/Generation 2022.

Comment: You can't have duplicate column names in a dataframe. Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `apply` a lambda that compares row with list:

```
out = df.filter(like='SNP').apply(lambda x: x.tolist()==['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], axis=1).sum()
```

Another is to use numpy and use its vectorized operations:

```
out = (df.filter(like='SNP').to_numpy() == np.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'])[:, None]).all(axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
1  # there is only one row that matches the list in that order
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grp = df.set_index(["Line", "Generation"]).apply(tuple, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df.groupby(["Line", "Generation", grp]).size())
# Line  Generation              
# A     2022        (A, C, C, G)    2
#                   (A, C, T, C)    1
# B     2021        (A, A, A, A)    1
# dtype: int64
```